# iOS push notification size limit and chat application

Tags: ios, push-notification, chat

we're doing chat application for mobile phones using push technology.

The idea is that messages are sent in pushes, so that we keep battery life, avoiding background loop with constant requests to server.

Currently the main problem is iOS message limitation of payload to 256.

Has anyone encounter this problem? What would be the best way to solve it?

Comment: There is no workaround of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building a chat application using push notification is not a good idea, because push notification is not intended to deliver data, so payload is not your main issue, since there is no guarantee of delivery of push notifications according to [apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9):

> Delivery of notifications is a “best effort”, not guaranteed. It is
>   not intended to deliver data to your app, only to notify the user that
>   there is new data available.

Thus you need to use something else until iOS7 is released, because iOS 7 has new background fetching modes, unfortunately I can explain more due to the NDA, so you can log to apple's forum and read about that.

Until that you cant start with [Socket based iphone app](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server) awesome tutorial by Cesare Rocchi.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is to instead send an identifier to distinguish the data in the push message, and then have the application download it once the message is opened.